# Настройка ssl на nginx

Tags: nginx, ssl, amazon-web-services

Ребят спасайте :)

Есть nginx (на aws амазона) пытаюсь настроить ssl, делаю следующее:

1. **С**обираю бандл из сертификатов (сертификат -> промежуточный -> корневой) и заливаю на сервер в папку /etc/nginx/ssl
2. **С**оздаю модуль в conf.d (gamerbro.conf) и вбиваю настройки ssl

```
server {
    listen              443 ssl;
    ssl_certificate     /etc/nginx/ssl/www_gamerbro_ru.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/private.key;
    server_name         www.gamerbro.ru;
}
```

1. **П**роверяю конфиг sudo nginx -t (Все успешно)
2. **П**ерезапускаю sudo service nginx restart (sudo nginx -s reload)

И ничего, не заходит по https (порт 443 на амазоне открыт), в чем может быть проблема? *(нужна будет информация, дополню вопрос, ссылка gamerbro.ru)*

Comment: Dns настроен? В чём конкретно выражается «не заходит»?

Comment: Что говорит выполненная на хосте команда  `sudo lsof -i4@0:443|grep -i listen`? И да, попробуйте директиву listen прописать как `listen *:443 ssl;`

Comment: @AlexeyTen dns вроде как да, домен был куплен у rucenter (nic.ru), делегировал через route 53 (gamerbro.ru)

Comment: @Oxyd nginx   18995     root    8u  IPv4 141798      0t0  TCP *:https (LISTEN)
nginx   19122 www-data    8u  IPv4 141798      0t0  TCP *:https (LISTEN)

Comment: Вы же сами прописали с www... А он у вас не настроен как алиас в dns!

Comment: @ヒミコИмеете ввиду поставить в server_name gamerbro.ru; ? (если да, то поставил, к сожалению ничего)

Comment: @frog-frofov Так, ладно, идём дальше. Вывод `sudo iptables -L | nc termbin.com 9999` И ссылку которую выдаст -- сюда в комменты.

Comment: @Oxyd https://termbin.com/7mps

Comment: @FrogFrogov Ага! Сказали сибирские мужики! Введите вот это: `sudo iptables -A ufw-user-input -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT` и скажите мне, я проверю, если всё удачно, мы наконец это добъём. ;-)

Comment: @Oxyd Еп, готово

Comment: @FrogFrogov Что-то не алё, повторите ту команду, что-б убедиться что правило добавилось. `sudo iptables -L --line-numbers | nc termbin.com 9999`

Comment: @Oxyd termbin.com/dwto

Comment: @FrogFrogov Какие-то чудеса... В цепочке правил [всё добавилось](https://i.imgur.com/ISsVRcp.png) но снаружи не достучаться... Ок. Пойдём другим путём. Остановите nginx... Запустите эту команду: `watch -t echo qu-qu | sudo nc -l 443` И скажите мне как будете готовы. Если файрвол пропускает подключения, то я увижу сообщение qu-qu Ну и сам смогу написать сообщение. ;-)

Comment: @Oxyd Такс, готово

Comment: @FrogFrogov Блин... Фигвам, называется, можете грохать по crl-c... Давайте  я чат создам, а то тут уже как-то длинно. А у самого амазона нет каких-нить хитрых настроек по поводу того какие порты разрешены?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103783/discussion-between-frog-frogov-and-oxyd).